# "Converting" project from old to new technology?

Tags: office-365, spfx-webparts, display-template, pnp-powershell, typescript

I am working on a SharePoint project which started a couple of years ago. It started with SP 2013 on - prem, and we are now on SP 2016 with feature pack 2. 
In the project we used the Powershell based [SPSD](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=spsd) (SharePoint Soultions Deployer) to provision and deploy artifacts, along with some other full trust solutions (.wsp's) and pure c# integration. 
Now we want to use the modern tools like pnp and spfx webparts, and I am not sure how to build those in to our oldschool solution.

I.e we use a lot of display templates, and upload web parts with spsd. We want to port those over in to the pnp-framework, so when we run an update all the display templates get updated etc.

Looking for some ideas/guide for how to go from oldschool to more modern framework in our project. 
Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

There is guidance available from Microsoft around moving your existing customisations to SharePoint Framework:

https://dev.office.com/blogs/converting-existing-js-apps-to-sharepoint-framework

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/migrate-script-editor-web-part-customizations

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/guidance/migrate-jslink-to-spfx-extensions

Comment: Thanks for the links, Vardhaman. More spesifically, I am looking for a guide to convert feature-framework to pnp-framework.